# how to use for loop inside HTML template

Tags: html, jstl

I have an html template which I use in marionette view . I pass a parameter in the template when I call it inside the render function . I want to add multiple div elements depending on the value of the parameter .How can I add for loop inside html template??

```html
<div id="mainArea">
    <div data-role="view">
        <div id="scrollView" data-role="scrollView" data-stretch="true">
            <div id = 'leftArrowImage' class="leftArrowImage">
            </div>

            <div id = 'mainViewArea'></div>
            <div id = 'rightArrowImage'></div>
           
            
           /* I have passed a variable here named allWidgets. I want to add the number of divs(<div data-role="page" ></div>) equal to the length of allWidgets array. How do I do that*/ 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using? The answer depends on what you're using to build the HTML.

Comment: I want to add code using JSTL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Widgets/ReportWidget/styles/scrollLayout.css"/>

<div id="mainArea">
    <div data-role="view">
        <div id="scrollView" data-role="scrollView" data-stretch="true">
            <div id = 'leftArrowImage' class="leftArrowImage">
            </div>

            <div id = 'mainViewArea'></div>
            <div id = 'rightArrowImage'></div>
            <%  var i;
            for i in allWidgets{ %>
                <div data-role="page" class="pages"  >
            </div>
            }%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this should help

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about(I am not sure that understand the question exactly),Could you try this;

```
<div id="mainArea">
    <div data-role="view">
        <div id="scrollView" data-role="scrollView" data-stretch="true">
            <div id = 'leftArrowImage' class="leftArrowImage">
            </div>
            <div id = 'mainViewArea'></div>
            <div id = 'rightArrowImage'></div>


           <c:forEach var="widget" items="${allWidgets}">
                 // Here, you can add parameters about widget objects in allWidgets
                 <div data-role="page" ></div> 
           </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You must also define the top of your jsp file below code,

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Comment: okay putting it simply i want to use for loop inside a file with extension .html . How do I do that??

Comment: You must use javascript to use loop in .html. This question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554355/javascript-to-loop-increment-html-code-with-values-up-to-55